# How To Write to File in every iteration of loop in Apache Flink?

Tags: java, apache-flink

I am new to Apache Flink. I have to filter all files in my computer and write them into one file. But in Flink, it appears to be impossible to write to an existing file. How can I handle it?

Comment: Why do you need to append to an existing file?

Comment: Because I have to find all mails via searching in all files.How to read the all files from starting root in Flink .Is there any way to do that? I tried to make ,first listing all files then in each iteration using filter operation and write to a file.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is use all files as your source for the Flink workflow, not by processing one file at a time in an iteration. Typically you do this by adding paths to a Hadoop job conf, e.g. here's an example from code I use reading sequence (binary) files.

```java
        Job job = Job.getInstance();
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(options.getCrawlDir()));

        HadoopInputFormat<Tuple, Tuple> inputFormat =  HadoopInputs.createHadoopInput(new SequenceFileInputFormat<Tuple, Tuple>(), 
                Tuple.class, Tuple.class, job);

        DataSet<HomePageText> homePageData =  env.createInput(inputFormat)
```